# CKeditor - IE issue when re-initializing inline editor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am not sure if this is a bug in CKeditor or IE or if I am missing something. 
On my webpage I allowing users to modify different content elements by doubling clicking the element and it initializes the editor.  The editor is destroyed after finishing the edit and the user can move on to another content element.
The issue is if an element is destroyed and then initialized again, the enter key will run twice (add two

elements), if it is destroyed again and initialized it will do it 3 times and so on. Other keys seem to run fine.

Is there something else that needs to be done other than:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['edit'].destroy();
```

A simple example is posted here http://jsfiddle.net/ByPW9/
To test:
Press init and you will see the enter gives you one break.
Press Destroy and init and you will see the enter gives you two breaks.
And so on

This is happening to me in IE10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further testing has not proven fruitful. Submitted bug to CKeditor development.
http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10561